# Dual of the subspace of sequences with finite non-zero entries

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

I found the following question in the book *Introdução à Análise Funcional*, by César R. Oliveira.

> Let $\mathcal{N}_p \subset \mathcal{l}^p(\Bbb{N})$, $1 \le p \le \infty,$ the subspace of all sequences with finitely many non-zero entries. Show that $\mathcal{N}^{\ast}_p=\mathcal{l}^q(\Bbb{N})$, with $(1/p)+(1/q)=1.$

I think something is strange in this exercise. The definition of $\mathcal{N}_p$ is independent of $p$, since all sequencies with finitely many non-zero entries belong to all $\mathcal{l}^p$. In other words, $\mathcal{N}_p=\mathcal{N_q}$, for all $p,q$. But that would imply, for example, that
$\mathcal{l}^1=\mathcal{N}^{\ast}_{\infty}=\mathcal{N}^{\ast}_{1}=\mathcal{l}^{\infty}$.

Is my reasoning correct? Where I made a mistake?

If I am wrong and the exercise is correct, I would appreciate any hints to solve it, I am lost.

EDIT: After posting, I realized my mistake. As pointed in the answer below, the norms are different, making the $\mathcal{N}_p$ different. However, I still need help to prove the exercise.

Thank you!

Comment: They're isomorphic as linear spaces, but the norms are different. The norm defines continuity, and $N_p^*$ is the _continuous_ dual.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate question. Searching...

Comment: ...Didn't find anything. @Célio - You need to show that any element of $\ell^q$, acting on $N_p$, is a well-defined continuous linear function; and conversely, given any continuous linear function on $N_p$, you can construct a sequence in $\ell^q$ that has the same effect as this function.

Comment: @mr_e_man You are right; I thought it's infinitely many for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of $\mathcal{N}_p$ itself indeed do not depend on $p$. However, when you consider the dual you have to specify which your norm you put on the space and that's where the $p$-dependency kicks in.